# Is SLURM Controller and "Worker" in the same node possible?

Tags: ubuntu, slurm

I have four nodes which are designed to be "worker" computing nodes. Since I lack another machine to act as "head" node, I'm thinking of using one of the nodes as the "controller", but can also be the "worker" at the same time. Is this setup possible? How can I do this? And if so, is it advisable to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this setup possible?

Just add the node to the partition.

For example, if my frontend was:

```
ControlMachine=frontend
```

I would configure it in my node list:

```
NodeName=frontend CoresPerSocket=6 Sockets=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 ...
NodeName=node00 CoresPerSocket=6 Sockets=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 ...
NodeName=node01 CoresPerSocket=6 Sockets=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 ...  
NodeName=node02 CoresPerSocket=6 Sockets=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 ...
```

And finally I would add them to the partition:

```
PartitionName=main Nodes=frontend,node00,node01,node02
```

> And if so, is it advisable to do so?

I guess that it is not a production cluster, so it won't be a problem. Of course, that node will be more loaded, but you are not likely to notice it.